# VBA - scripting.dictionary exclude blank

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

It is possible with `scripting.dictionary` exclude blank from range?
I am using this code to find special values from range. I don´t need excel formula for range, but solution in VBA (if exist).

With this code I have in listbox always one blank item.

```
Dim v, e

With Sheets("DATA").Range("NAMED_RANGE")
    v = .Value
End With

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .Exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.TextBox121.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DICTIONARY").Range("B2").Resize(UBound(.keys), 1).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```

Comment: Add If e.Value<>"" Then before checking If Not .Exists(e)...

Comment: `If Not .Exists(e) And e<>vbNullString Then .Add e, Nothing` as @ShaiRado said

Comment: @R3uK This code from you working, but If range has only one value there is error ("Application-defined or object-deffined error")

Comment: @Nataniell : Yeah, on the line `v = .Value`, try my answer to see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim v, e

With Sheets("DATA").Range("NAMED_RANGE")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 1 Then
        v = .Value
    Else
        v = .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End If
End With

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .Exists(e) And e <> vbNullString Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.TextBox121.List = Application.Transpose(.Keys)

    If .Count And UBound(.Keys)>0 Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DICTIONARY").Range("B2").Resize(UBound(.Keys), 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(.Keys)
End With
```

Comment: Hmm still same error. My data in range looks like:
empty,
empty,
TEST,
empty,
empty,
TEST,

Comment: This line  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DICTIONARY").Range("B2").Resize(UBound(.Keys), 1).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(.Keys)`
error ("Application-defined or object-deffined error")

Comment: @Nataniell : Try the edit, it's probably because there is not keys! ;)

Comment: Now error:Object requierd on the line `If .Keys.Count > 0 Then `

Comment: @Nataniell : give it another try! ;)

Comment: @Nataniell : Glad I could help! ;)